# Statistical analysis is very subjective

Tags: normality-assumption

After studying probability theory and inferential statistics by the famous Cassela and Berger's book, I'm starting to try my own analysis, of course, just small stuff only for training.

I'm trying to know if the column named Tip from the famous dataset called [TIPS](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/regclass/versions/1.6/topics/TIPS) is normally distributed or not.

This looked like an easy task but it's not. That's what I did so far:

1. I can't use normality tests like Shapiro-Wiki, they aren't reliable because the impact of the sample size on these tests.
2. I can't use histograms either, in order to have a good choice of the number of bins I need to know if the data is normally distributed or not, for example Scott's and Sturges choices are more suitable for normal distributions instead of Friedmann-Diaconis choice.
3. I've analysed the skewness and the kurtosis of the data, which gives me 1.45 and 3.64 with minor differences between fisher and moment methods. I've heard different suitable ranges, I don't think there is a consensus here.
4. What left for me is using the Q-Q plot:

[image]

However this is highly subjective, there are some points fitted on the line but the tails are going further. I wouldn't bet my family savings on that. So how can I know how far from normality is good for me? Are there any method missing in my analysis? I fell hopeless, all this are very subjective for me as a former pure mathematician who are trying to become a statistician someday. **I really need help!**

Comment: We would expect 95% of points to be between +/-2 and 99% between +/-3 . We would expect virtually zero to be more than 4 or 5 in modulus. You have some residuals as big as 10 in modulus, the probability of this is basically zero.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question "normally distributed or not" is very easy:  The answer is ALWAYS "not."  So dismiss that question and move on.  The more important questions are "In what ways does the distribution differ from normality?" and "how much does it matter?"

Regarding the first question, your q-q plot shows the skewness very clearly.  It also shows evidence of discrete components in that there are horizontal lines. If nothing else, this helps you to understand your data better - maybe there are some issues to investigate that you had not anticipated before.  (This is the essence of "exploratory data analysis.")

The answer to question "does it matter?"  depends on the purpose of the analysis.  If you are interested on predicting a new data value, it matters a great deal.  If you are constructing a confidence interval for a mean, it matters less.  If you are constructing a confidence interval for a standard deviation, it matters a great deal. More study is needed here.  Simulation is also very helpful.

Comment: It was just a training, I think I should have had an objective in mind. I feel so dumb now lol